# How to properly implement jQuery's .animate() method using an external javascript file?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, client-side

I am currently working on developing a professional portfolio for future job opportunities. I am fairly new to all of the concepts I am practicing and have run into an issue utilizing jQuery's .animate() method. I seem to have no problem using jQuery's .css() method, but as soon as I attempt to implement .animate() nothing happens.

Because I am using Bootstrap and Semantic along with my own custom CSS and javascript files, I have attempted to rearrange the CDNs and Script tags, however nothing has changed.

Currently the order is:
In the head: 
Bootstrap CSS CDN
Bootstrap js CDN
Semantic CSS CDN
Relative Custom CSS

Before the closing body tag:
jQuery js CDN
Popper js CDN
Semantic js CDN
Relative Custom js (where the code in question is located)

```html
<button class="ui green basic button" id="click">Click</button>
<div id="trans">
    <h4>Hello World</h4>
</div>
```

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#trans').animate({
        width: "50%"
    }, 500, function(){
        alert("animated");
    });
});
This Does Nothing
```

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#trans').css({
        width: "50%"
    });
});
This Works As Intended
```

I would expect upon clicking the button with id ="click", that the div with id ="trans" would reduce width from 100% down to 50% and produce an alert stating "animated", however nothing happens at all. The oddest part of this to me is that if I utilize the .css() method to change the same property, it works flawlessly but without the fun animation look.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you just aren't seeing it? https://jsfiddle.net/xbLrpsk6/3/

I did set some initial CSS on the #trans DIV

```
#trans {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

```
<button class="ui green basic button" id="click">Click</button>
    <div id="trans" style="background-color: #f00;">
        <h4>Hello World</h4>
    </div>
```

In JavaScript

```
$('#click').click(function(){
          $('#trans').animate({
              width: "50%"
          },500,function(){
            alert("animated");
          });
      });
```

Everything looks fine. Check out: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/XwpWXz)

Maybe, you may have changed something in CDN files.